# d3 unable to access data by selected item in drop-down menu

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, drop-down-menu

I am trying to use a drop-down menu to access a particular column of a csv.

My html code is here:

```
<select id="myList" >
  <option value="firstCol">One</option>
  <option value="secondCol">Two</option>
  <option value="thirdCol">Three</option>  
  <option value="fourthCol">Four</option>
</select>
```

below in my script, I read in my csv, then call the createList function here:

```
function createList(){
    var current = document.getElementById("myList");
    var strUser = current.options[current.selectedIndex].value;

    data2.forEach(function(d2){
       console.log(d2.firstCol); <- prints each value in the correct column
       console.log(strUser);    <- prints the correct selected item
       console.log(d2.strUser); <- prints undefined
    });
 }
```

If I print out d2.firstCol, it gives me the right answer. If I have firstCol selected and print out strUser, it prints "firstCol." 
Why then does d2.strUser return undefined?

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the error because you don't have a column named "strUser". You need to use the "indexing" operator in this case:

```
d2[strUser];
```